# Restricting the boundaries of Drawing in a UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView with an image, the view has been set to aspect fit therefore when I load new images the size of the image alters.

On top of that UIImageView is another UIImageView where I am allowing the user to draw a line around a person in the image.

This all works perfectly, however I am able to draw outwith the image(still in the UIImageView). Is it possible to restrict the boundaries of drawing to be the size of the image rather than the view?

I have worked out the width and height of images in the view, however when I put these in as parameters to drawInRect it no longer draws on screen.

This works perfectly for drawing in the complete view:

```
[self.drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
```